# What is the difference between using the box keyword and Box::new?

Tags: rust, heap-memory

Is `box` just syntactic sugar or can it be applied to use cases where `Box::new` is not sufficient? I read somewhere that `box` is unstable, does that mean I can only use it with the nightly Rust versions?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`Box::new` is just a function, like any other function.  It is not special in any way whatsoever.  It is grubby and smells faintly of very-close-to-the-expiration date cheese.

`box` is magic and made up ground-up pixies and the dreams of little children.  It is dressed in the finest, swankiest clothes and carries with it the faint aroma of freshly cut pine.

When you execute `Box::new(e)`, because it is a function, `e` must be completely evaluated and constructed *before* it can start the call.  If this means allocating and filling a 500kB structure on the stack, then it has to allocate and fill a 500kB structure on the stack, *and then* pass that to `Box::new`, which *only then* can allocate the space on the heap (which might fail), *and then* copy that 500kB into the heap.

When you execute `box e`, because it is wonderful like a cool breeze on a hot summer's day, the compiler can reorder things such that it *begins* by allocating the 500kB on the heap, *and then* filling the 500kB structure *directly on the heap*.  And then it's done.  No extra copying, no chewing through stack space.  No wasted effort if that "allocate on the heap" thing fails to work out.

`box` is life, `box` is love; all hail `box`!

(And yes, as of writing, it's still unstable which means you need a nightly compiler to bask in its radiance.  But *soon*, the dawn will come.  Get it?  Dawn?  Nightly?  ...  I'll show myself out...)

Comment: Isn't the `box` keyword supposed to cover custom allocations (ie, allocating something *else* than a `Box`) ? Or is it to be replaced by placement `<-` ?

Comment: `box` will support things other than `Box` (*e.g.* `Rc`, `Arc`, *etc.*) via inference.  `<-` is the current provisional syntax for *placement*, which is related, but different: `box` creates a new place to put a value and then puts it there, `<-` places a value in an *existing* place (like, say, on the end of a vector).

Comment: I enjoyed every part of this answer - I also learned something.

Comment: @DK. ["Placement new" (RFC 809) is no more](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27779#issuecomment-378416911) as of April 2018.