# Stack overflow with heap buffer?

Tags: rust

I have the following code to read from a file:

```
let mut buf: Box<[u8]> = Box::new([0; 1024 * 1024]);
while let Ok(n) = f.read(&mut buf) {
    if n > 0 {
        resp.send_data(&buf[0..n]);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

But it causes:

```
fatal runtime error: stack overflow
```

I am on OS X 10.11 with Rust 1.12.0.

Comment: What is `f` is in this case?

Comment: it's a mio::tcp::TcpStream

Comment: what is the value of n when the code crashes?

Comment: What's the default size of your stack? Because `Box::new([0; 1024 * 1024])` will allocate 1MB on the stack prior to moving it to the box.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Ugh. Is there a way to allocate directly on the heap?

Comment: @ElefEnt: It's in the works ([placement_new_protocol](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27779)). In the mean time, I advise creating a `Vec` and then converting it to a `Box` via [`into_boxed_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_boxed_slice).

Comment: For this particular case, using Vec or Box doesn't matter, so you could also just use Vec and not convert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Matthieu said, `Box::new([0; 1024 * 1024])` will currently overflow the stack due to initial stack allocation. If you are using Rust Nightly, the `box_syntax` feature will allow it to run without issues:

```
#![feature(box_syntax)]

fn main() {
    let mut buf: Box<[u8]> = box [0; 1024 * 1024]; // note box instead of Box::new()

    println!("{}", buf[0]);
}
```

You can find additional information about the difference between `box` and `Box::new()` in the following question: [What the difference is between using the box keyword and Box::new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201250/what-the-difference-is-between-using-the-box-keyword-and-boxnew/35201819).

Comment: Will it really overflow the stack? I mean, it's only 1MB, which is not THAT much. I know some OSes have tight limits by default, but I don't know if OS X is one of them.

Comment: Well, that is the error that is reported; perhaps it is bogus, but I'm not sure how to investigate it further.